# Unwanted "US" character in XML (not Escape-Characters, no "nul")

Tags: xml

I have already reduced all the characters with meanings (&, <, > ect.) and all "nul"-characters from the strings, but there is another smybol I do now know how to get rid of:

[image]

I have already reduced all the "nul"-characters via java, I would do the same with this, but I do not know it's name and it's difficult to google. Please help.

```
public static String reduceNULvalues (String string){
    string = string.replace("\0", "");
    return string;      
}
```

Best, Yvonne

Comment: I'm not going to install Google Drive to look at a file. Stack Overflow is intended to be a future resource for other people with the same problem, and that can't happen if you post the data to an external site. Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28459715/edit) your question to include the bad data; post a hex dump if it includes control characters.

Comment: I am sorry, I was under the impression that the picture is publicly available and viewable for everybody, as it is posted in my PublicFolder. I cannot embedd pictures here, as I am still a too new member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a control character named *Unit separator*, `^_`, decimal 31, hex 1F – see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#C0_.28ASCII_and_derivatives.29:

> Can be used as delimiters to mark fields of data structures. If used for hierarchical levels, US is the lowest level (dividing plain-text data items), while RS, GS, and FS are of increasing level to divide groups made up of items of the level beneath it.

Comment: Thank you CBroe. I cannot give you a "Vote up" ye4t, because I need 15 reputation points for that. As soon as I have gained them, I will come back and do this. Thanks to you I do know yet how to get rid of this. Have a nice day.

Comment: I looked at it via Hex Editor, it is indeed the "1F".